# in the Table view I want to add some images but when I run it doesn't show and I already import the images in assets.xcassets

Tags: swift, xcode

I already make an array to access the picture.. Can someone help? thanks

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class MainMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



    let labeltitle = ["Acme De la Vie Tee", "Anti Social Social Club Black Hoodie", "CDG Play Gold Black Tee"]

    let labelprice = [("RM 240"), ("RM 305"), ("RM 418")]

    let myImage = [UIImage(named: "adlv1"), UIImage(named: "assc"), UIImage(named: "cdg1")]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self


    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labeltitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MainMenuTableViewCell


        cell.label11?.text = labeltitle[indexPath.row]

        cell.label2?.text = labelprice[indexPath.row]

        cell.myImage.image = self.myImage[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is my code for `MainMenuTableViewCell`

```swift
import UIKit

class MainMenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label11: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your tableviewcell  in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(MainMenuTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register)

[More Info](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse)

Answer (score -1):

Did u add constraint ?
Select to viewController and do reset the suggested constraint and im sure it will be solved

Comment: um yeah, I already fix the constraints and still didn't show anything

Answer (score -1):

cell.myImage.image = self.myImage[indexPath.row]

try to change your image Array name